# spring mvc resources are not accessible

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I dont understand, why all recommendations don't work when I try to access static resources configured by .

All I need is to include Jquery. With the remote google-url it works, but I can't access it from my own resources:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.js" var="jqueryJs" />
<script src="${jqueryJs}"></script>
```

Here is my project structure:

[image]

**web.xml**

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"
    version="3.0">

```
<display-name></display-name>



<!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans. For example @Controller 
        and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="indoorGPS" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

I found out that, it I add

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to the web.xml, the resources are found, but again: I don't understand why this "default-servlet" solves the problem and why mvc:resources is ignored (i can delete it and it has no effect at all).

**here is the way I access the resource in the jsp:**

[image]

What have I done wrong? And why does it behave like that?

Comment: `<url-pattern>` for Spring Dispatcher servlet should be `/*` in your web.xml so that any request to any resource including static files comes to your Dispatcher servlet. Once the control comes there, based on your `mvn:resources` config, if your static file URL contains `/resources/` in it, it will serve the resource by mapping them directly to your `resources` folder.

Comment: unfortunately this causes a stackoverflow error and does not work. did it for you?

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace to your question ?